# Create an object by passing a list of object IDs using mongoengine in Python

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoengine

I have a document having a key with a value of type list which store `ObjectID`s referencing to other documents like below:

```
{
    docs: [
        ObjectId('61c9d3bfdd8183b4f61d3124'),
        ObjectId('61c9d3cadd8183b4f61d3127')
    ]
}
```

I want to create an object and query the documents with the specific ObjectID. Do you know how am I supposed to that? I am using mongoengine and Python coding language.
Normally, in order to return documents with specific key values, I use below code:

```
sample_obj = test.objects(testid = 2)
```

Comment: This is how you query with the _native_ MongoDB Query Language (I am not familiar with Mongoengine ODM):  [Query an Array](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/#query-an-array-for-an-element).

Comment: I think it is the other way around. I want to do in the opposite order

Comment: Then you can use the `$in` operator (of MongoDB native query).